# Passing Class<? extends T> as a parameter

Tags: java, generics, reflection

This is some code that I hope gives you an understanding of what I want. It does not work of course.

```
public static <T> void foo(Class<? extends T> type, AsyncCallback<T> callback){
    /*do something */
}



public void MyMethod() {
    Class a;
    if (isSomething()) {
        a = "some class";
    } else if (isSomething2()){
        a = "some other class";
    }
    /* probably more of this or even a switch*/
    useFoo(a);
}

public void useFoo(Class a){
    foo(a.class, AsyncCallback<a> {
        /* some callback */
    });
}
```

Method foo is already there and I need to use it dynamically from MyMethod. Currently there is one useFoo for each different if statement in MyMethod. I want to have only one useFoo that would be called with some parameters. The reason is that the callback is a lengthy piece of code which needs to be repeated in every call for that method. How can I accomplish this without changing foo method? I hope you understand my problem. Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to make your `useFoo()` method generic. Generics can only take reference type names in between `<>`, not references themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the rest of the code the same as above, you can write your `useFoo` method as:

```
public <T> void useFoo(Class<T> a) {
    foo(a, new AsyncCallback<T>() {
        /* some callback */
    });
}
```

Comment: However, i can't seem to call methods in the class that I pass to it. For example in the callback I currently have 
    public void onSuccess(T result) {
        class.run();
    }   and it asks me to cast the class manually

Comment: You mean `a.run()`? `a` has type `Class<T>` and objects of type `Class` don't have a method `run()`. Maybe you need to post a fuller example.

Comment: I mean, how do I call the run method which exists in the class I call useFoo with. In your example it being a. But `a.run()` does not work.

Comment: A `Class` does not have a `run` method. An instance of the class could have a `run` method though. `public <T extends Runnable> void useFoo(final Class<T> a) { foo(a, new AsyncCallback<T>() { public void onSuccess(T result) { try { a.newInstance().run(); } catch (Exception e) { } } }); }`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
public <T> void useFoo(T a) {
    foo(a);
    // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare the specific `T` type in a static function like this:

```
ClassName.<ConcreteTType>foo(tObject.class, callbackstuff);
```